# Adding UIView from the center of the parent UIView

Tags: ios, uiview, cgpoint

i can't understand how i can add a `UIView` to a second `UIView` starting from the center of the second `UIView` and not to the top left corner, i'm making an example:
i want add a `UIView` to this `CGPoint`: (-96,96), and the second `UIView` it's a square rectangle 300x300 so i want add the `UIView` starting from the center, instead the `UIVIew` is added starting from the top left corner and when it's added go out of the screen, this is an example:

```
          ________________
          |              |
   y      |   x          |
          |       .      |
          |              |
          |              |
          |______________|

x = where i want should go the UIView
y = where instead it's added
```

how i can fix it?

EDIT:
i add the UIView in this way:

```
UIView *v = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 70, 70)];
v.center = CGPointMake(-96,96);
[self.squareView addSubview:v];
```

Comment: Please show the code you are using to add the view

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
UIView *v = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 70, 70)];
v.center = squareView.center;

var frame:CGRect = v.frame
frame.origin.x -= 96
frame.origin.y += 96
v.frame = frame

[self.squareView addSubview:v];
```

Comment: log v.frame and squareView.frame after each line to see what's happening. Does v goes to center, what is the initial squareView.frame etc.

Comment: i have fixed making a converting between the square view and the value with a simple math operation, thanks anyway